# Ubuntu Server hanging on adding swap

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, swap

A fresh install of Ubuntu Server is refusing to boot and hanging on "Adding 524284k swap on /dev/mapper/test--vg-swap_1. Priority:-1 extents:1 across:524284k

I can get around this by dropping onto recovery mode and just resuming to a normal boot.

Answer (score 20):

It is doing this because Ubuntu is trying to switch to a high resolution video mode for the console and your hardware isn't cooperating.

**Fixing this while at the machine**

When Grub2 shows up:

- Highlight the menu item for Ubuntu and press 'e'
- Go to the line where it loads the kernel and press 'End' to go to the end of the line
- Add 'nomodeset'
- Press F10 or Ctrl-X to boot it

With any luck it will boot into the login screen. This won't save that option but at least now you can edit the file for Grub2 and update it to save that option if it works.
I [blogged](http://blog.jamesrhall.com/2014/04/ubuntu-server-1404-fun.html) about this recently.

**Fixing this for good**

- Log in (ssh will probably do, if you know the machine's IP)
- Update the grub config file `nano /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
- Edit the line to include `nomodeset`, in my case, the line looked like this afterwards: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`
- Save/exit nano
- Run `update-grub`
- Reboot

Comment: Thank you! For others, the line you add `nomodeset` to is the line that starts with `linux /boot/vmlinuz...`, not the `initrd` line.

Comment: Note: The easy way of doing this with modern versions of GRUB is by editing /etc/default/grub and add "nomodeset" (separated by a space) to the end of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Mac Mini.

Comment: @Ernie: then `update-grub`.

Comment: Gauthier: you're right! Thanks, and +1

Comment: solution also works for ubuntu 14.04. I took the liberty of incorporating your comments into the answer (it it's accepted, that is).

Comment: There is no `/etc/init/grub` file on my Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop nor Kali Linux. I have used `/etc/default/grub` instead.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Thanks, I overlooked that somehow. I fixed the reference.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add it? You may want to format the swap again. What you can do is boot under rescue mode, mount the vgs and do:

```
# mkswap /dev/mapper/test--vg-swap_1

# swapon /dev/mapper/test--vg-swap_1
```

Then add it again to the /etc/fstab if it's not present.